# How to specify the windows version for the host node for Windows Server Containers on Azure Kubernetes Service?

Tags: azure-aks, windows-container, windows-server-container

I am following the guide on how to create Windows Server Containers on Azure Kubernetes Service. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us//azure/aks/windows-container-cli)

I pulled the sample image(mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples:aspnetapp) demonstrated in the guide, tagged it and uploaded it to Azure container registry.
Upon deploying the application to Kubernetes, the pods are unable to pull the image from the container registry. I also tried using the original image from Docker hub leading to the same issue.

Below is the output of `kubectl describe` command on one of the pods

```
Name:               hello-world-56c76d8549-7248k
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               aksnpwin000000/10.240.0.35
Start Time:         Sat, 01 Jun 2019 19:33:21 +0530
Labels:             app=hello-world
                    pod-template-hash=56c76d8549
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:                 10.240.0.47
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/hello-world-56c76d8549
Containers:
  hello-world:
    Container ID:
    Image:          pocaspnetcoreweb.azurecr.io/pocaspnetcoreweb:v1
    Image ID:
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  800m
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     300m
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-m647n (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-m647n:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-m647n
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  beta.kubernetes.io/os=windows
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                   From                     Message
  ----     ------          ----                  ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled       18m                   default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/hello-world-56c76d8549-7248k to aksnpwin000000
  Normal   SandboxChanged  17m                   kubelet, aksnpwin000000  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  Failed          17m (x3 over 17m)     kubelet, aksnpwin000000  Failed to pull image "pocaspnetcoreweb.azurecr.io/pocaspnetcoreweb:v1": [rpc error: code = Unknown desc = a Windows version 10.0.18362-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.17763 host, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://pocaspnetcoreweb.azurecr.io/v2/pocaspnetcoreweb/manifests/v1: unauthorized: authentication required]
  Normal   Pulling         16m (x4 over 17m)     kubelet, aksnpwin000000  Pulling image "pocaspnetcoreweb.azurecr.io/pocaspnetcoreweb:v1"
  Warning  Failed          2m55s (x65 over 17m)  kubelet, aksnpwin000000  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

The Events section has an event with the message

```
Warning  Failed          17m (x3 over 17m)     kubelet, aksnpwin000000  Failed to pull image "pocaspnetcoreweb.azurecr.io/pocaspnetcoreweb:v1": [rpc error: code = Unknown desc = a Windows version 10.0.18362-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.17763 host, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://pocaspnetcoreweb.azurecr.io/v2/pocaspnetcoreweb/manifests/v1: unauthorized: authentication required]
```

The message seems clear enough to me since it complaints about the windows version mismatch between the container and the host.

My kubernetes deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  labels:
    app: hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: hello-world
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": windows
      containers:
      - name: hello-world
        image: pocaspnetcoreweb.azurecr.io/pocaspnetcoreweb:v1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 800m
          requests:
            cpu: .1
            memory: 300m
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: acr-auth
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: sample
```

How do I make sure that the windows version match between the container and the host? Is there any way that I could specify the Windows version that will be used on the host?

Comment: It seems two problems the error shows, one is that the base image version is incompatible with your windows node. Try to use a base image with version 10.0.17763. Another is the authentication of your image from the ACR. Take a check.

Comment: Pull specific tag, otherwise it will try to match your dev workstation. So pull `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples:aspnetapp:aspnetapp-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` instead. Also your error message complaints about authentication failure to your CR not version mismatch

Comment: Yeah pulling specific tag was the solution to the issue. Also after I pulled the specific tag correctly the second error about the authentication was gone. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you cant do that (and if you think about it - it makes no sense, how do you dynamically change windows version on the host???). It has to be the other way around, find the image (or build the image) with the proper base host windows version.

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-samples/

Comment: Thank you!
I was able to deploy successfully using the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples:aspnetapp-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` image.